# Why SUBSTRING_INDEX in Hive is not working for negative count?

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

When I execute the following two queries, the SUBSTRING_INDEX function with positive count gives me correct result but the SUBSTRING_INDEX function with negative count gives me wrong output result.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('wwwbig.data.nsqlcom',"data", 1)
```

**Output**: wwwbig.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX("wwwbig.data.nsqlcom",'data', -1)
```

**Output**: ata.nsqlcom

As per the function definition, the second query should return ".nsqlcom" value. Note: This issue is only seen in the case of Hive and not any other tool.

Answer (score 0):

its working perfectly.
definition is -
`substring_index(STRING a, STRING delim, INT count)`
Returns the substring from string A before count occurrences of the delimiter delim (as of Hive 1.3.0).

- If count is positive, everything to the left of the final delimiter (counting from the left) is returned.
- If count is negative, everything to the right of the final delimiter (counting from the right) is returned.

In your second case, when count is -1 and delimiter is 'data', function should return everything to the right of delimiter based on final occurrence position of delimiter.
As per your data "wwwbig.data.nsqlcom", final occurrence of `data` is at 7. So, everything from 8th position will be returned which is `ata.nsqlcom`.